# How do I set up the rails models in a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on a blog rails app. I want to have each post have many tags as well as be able to display all the posts that belong to a given tag. I have gone through the set up for the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships following both the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and I also tried [this tutorial](http://shilpi2189.blogspot.com/2013/01/implementing-hasandbelongstomany.html).

Both times I went into rails console after the models were set up to check that the tables were formatted correctly. I called `Post.new` and `Tag.new`. Each gives me a new instance/entry in the table, but neither shows a column for referencing the other. Shouldn't there be one? If not, how should I be structuring my seed data?

Up to this point I have only being doing belongs_to and has_many relationships. I would also appreciate if anyone has a link to a better explanation/tutorial on `has_and_belongs_to_many`, my searching hasn't turned up much that is clear.

Here's my code:

`post.rb:`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  belongs_to :categories
end
```

`tag.rb:`

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

`longnumber_create_posts.rb:`

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :content
      t.datetime :pub_time
      t.integer :category_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`lognumber_create_tags.rb:`

```
class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`longnumber_create_posts_and_tags.rb:`

```
class CreatePostsAndTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts_tags, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :post, index: true
      t.belongs_to :tag, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

`schema.rb:`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151123235501) do

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "tag_id"
  end

  add_index "posts_tags", ["post_id"], name: "index_posts_tags_on_post_id"
  add_index "posts_tags", ["tag_id"], name: "index_posts_tags_on_tag_id"

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: It would be great if you can paste your database structure and your model here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a many to many relationship, using your example, you won't see a foreign key in the Post or Tag tables since it is using the "join" table you created named PostTags to store the relation.  As you've already setup the has_many and belongs_to associations in your 3 models (Post, Tag, PostTag), you must now tell Rails when to create the association between these posts and tags. This is done as follows:

```
@post = Post.new
@tag = Tag.last (The last is just an example, make sure to use the instance you need!

@post.tags << @tag   #This is where the magic happens and the association is formed
```

Lately most of the Rails community has moved towards using the "has_many through" approach since it allows extra attributes to be added to the join table whereas here you can only store foreign keys in the PostTag table.

UPDATE: As per the below comments regarding where this code goes:

Normally this goes in your controller but you can do this in the rails console as well.  For example if you had some form input for a post and added a tag-id to associate it when submitting the form your controller would most likely look like this:

```
def create
@post = Post.create(post_params)
if @post.save
@tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
@post.tags << @tag
redirect_to some_fun_path
else
render 'new'
end


private

def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:tag_id, :title, :description, etc.)
end
```

Comment: Are you calling this in rails console or is this going in a file?

Comment: Normally this goes in your controller but you can do this in the rails console as well.  For example:

Answer (score 1):

You've instantiated a Tag and Post individually but need to let one object know about the other. This association is made in the join table you created. You can establish these associations in a couple of ways:

**Option 1**

```
Post.create(name: text) # assuming your db was empty, this post now has id = 1
Tag.create(name: text, post_id: 1)
```

**Option 2**

```
post = Post.create(name: text)
tag = Tag.create(name: text)

# associate tag with post
post.tags << tag
```

Option 2 is probably more preferable and can usually be called in your controller. For example:

```
# in PostsController
def create
  post = Post.create(post_params)
  tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(params[:tag_id])
  post.tags << tag

  render root_path
end

private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :content, :pub_time, :category_id, :tag_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `create` on `Tag` and/or `Post`, otherwise the record wont stored in the database.

Below you'll create a post and a tag related to that post.

```
post = Post.create!(content: "my content")
post.tags.create!(name: "movies")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat `Tag` or `Post` like an array. For example:

`post = Post.create!(title: 'title')`

`tag = Tag.create!(name: 'test')`

`tag.posts << post`